# DataGridView not autosizing columns until show

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a custom control that essential shows a DataGridView popup when a button is clicked. I want to resize the popup to the size of the DataGridView columns. I have set the AutoSize modes when the DataGridView  is created.

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

I also call the following method right before calculating the total column size.

```
public void AutoResize()
{
    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
    dataGridView1.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells);
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

The first time the popup is shown it has not been resized properly. This, as far as I can tell, is because the AutoSize of the columns doesn't take place until the dataGridView control is displayed once.

This is the order of execution.

CreateCustomControl -> CreateDataGridView (with data) -> AddToCustomControl -> CallAutoResize -> ShowCustomControl (with DataGridView)

A simple solution is for me to resize the control after it is displayed. I still would like to know why the AutoResize doesn't take place until the control is shown?

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 0):

would this solution work for you

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = your DataSource would be assigned here;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

for ( int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++ )
{
    int colw = grd.Columns[i].Width;
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = colw;
}
```